# Getting 'module' object has no attribute 'bindtextdomain' launching meld

Tags: homebrew

I just did

```
 brew uninstall meld
 brew install meld
```

Trying to use meld continues to give same error:

```
15:46:50/config $!8420
meld config.bernoulli.py config.py
Couldn't bind the translation domain. Some translations won't work.
'module' object has no attribute 'bindtextdomain'
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.8_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display
  warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
/usr/local/Cellar/meld/1.8.6/libexec/bin/meld:155: GtkWarning: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  gtk.icon_theme_get_default().append_search_path(meld.paths.icon_dir())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/meld/1.8.6/libexec/bin/meld", line 155, in <module>
    gtk.icon_theme_get_default().append_search_path(meld.paths.icon_dir())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append_search_path'
```

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed this issue by uninstalling/reinstalling all versions of everything.

`$ APPS=$(brew list)
$ brew uninstall --force $APPS
$ brew install $APPS`